# Python, How to make a nested loop works with multiple columns csv files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nested-loops

I am new to Python, I want to make a function work using data from multiple columns CSV files, one row by one row with some delay in between each run.

This is want I want to achieve:

1. Read from first CSV file within a range ( e.g. row 0 to row 3)
2. Use the data of one row, to put in the right parameter section inside function, some delay and do the same with next row.
3. some delay, then it goes to next CSV file, until the last CSV file.

I have the tried the following code, but not working. The following code works fine with one column CSV file.

there are 4 parameter that I want to be filled with data from CSV file,
using the same Column header name as parameter name inside the function.

sample csv file:

```
img_path,desc_1 title_1,link_1
site.com/image22.jpg,someTitle,description1,site1.com
site.com/image32.jpg,someTitle,description2,site2.com
site.com/image44.jpg,someTitle,description3,site3.com
```

```py
from abc.zzz  import xyz
path_id_map = [
    {'path':'file1.csv', 'id': '12345678'},
    {'path':'file2.csv', 'id': '44556677'}
    {'path':'file3.csv', 'id': '33377799'}
    {'path':'file4.csv', 'id': '66221144'}]
s_id = None
for pair in path_id_map:
    with open(pair['path'], 'r') as f:
        for i in range(0, 3):      
            zzz.func1(img_path=f.readline().rstrip(','), title_1=f.readline().rstrip(','), 
            desc_1=f.readline().rstrip(','), link_1=f.readline().rstrip(','), B_id=pair['id'], 
            s_id=s_id)
            return zzz.func1(img_file=img_path, title_1=title_1, desc_1=desc_1, 
                 link_1=link_1, B_id=B_id, s_id=s_id)
            time.sleep(25)
```

Appreciate your help to make it work.

Comment: Have a look at python's csv module, it will make working with csv files easier for you. Here is a tutorial; https://realpython.com/python-csv/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Every time you call `readline()` you move over to the next line. So first save that line to a variable and then process it.
- [`rstrip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) only removes characters from the edges of the string. As you have no trailing commas, the use of [`rstrip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) in your code has no effect. It seems like you meant to use the [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method instead to take the different parts separated by commas.

```py
for pair in path_id_map:
    with open(pair['path'], 'r') as f:
        next(f)  # skip first header line
        for _ in range(0, 3):      
            line = next(f)
            img_path, desc_1, title_1, link_1 = map(str.strip, line.split(','))
            zzz.func1(img_path=img_path, title_1=title_1, desc_1=desc_1, 
                      link_1=link_1, B_id=pair['id'], s_id=s_id)
```

But there is no need to parse csv files manually. Instead, you can use the built-in [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module, which has the [`DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) that reads each line to a dict where the keys are the headers and the values are the value of each column with that header. This will allow you to simply [unpack the row into the function call](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/):

```py
import csv

for pair in path_id_map:
    with open(pair['path'], 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        for _ in range(0, 3):      
            line = next(reader)
            zzz.func1(B_id=pair['id'], s_id=s_id, **line)
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, I tried the both codes, I get error on "return"  `Return outside function` if I push forward the return line (indent) I get `unexpected indent`

Comment: That is because `return` can only be in a function... What do you expect it do outside of a function?

Comment: thanks, my bad, I tried the upper code, now I get error: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "'img_path '"` so I am checking what is wrong.

Comment: Well there are a few problems here. The first line is the header so we need to skip it, also it seems like there are spaces. Check the revised code. But anyway, why aren't you using the second one? It's much simpler and already skips the header automatically...

Comment: thank you very much for the help, I did used the wrong file with a different header,my bad, now I have change the header,  and I tried your edited upper code, I get this error: `image_path, description, title, link = map(str.strip, line.split(','))
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 4)`   header and parameters are now: `image_file=image_path, title=title, description=description, link=link`

Comment: I tried the second code, I get TypeError  `got an unexpected keyword argument ''image_path ''`

Comment: thank you for your code and help, now the code is working fine, the second code did not work, because it skips the header, as the result I got Variable not defined error, running the first code gave me error of too many values to unpack, because I had couple of commas in the description on my csv file, the delimited was also comma,  so I changed the delimiter to semi comma and problem solved.

Comment: @Dave99 Nice! Happy to help and that you could solve that little issue. I just think it would be much better using the second version. What's wrong with skipping the header? You don't really need to parse it... The first code also skips the header just the same...

Comment: Thanks, I tried to make the 2nd one works, but I could not make it work because of variable definition error, on the first code this line:
`img_path, desc_1, title_1, link_1 = map(str.strip, line.split(','))` helps the definition of variables.
I am working on how to save the index number of last run, to a text file,  
I want to run the file on schedule, so each time file runs, it reads this index number and use the data on row that left off, or maybe next line. and at the end write the last index number of used row to the same text file. If you give me hint I am grateful, maybe I post new.

Comment: @Dave99 not sure I fully understand, but those variables will always hold the data of the last row. In the second version you have that in the dict `line`. So instead of doing `img_path`, you can do `line['img_path']`. Does that help in any way?